# It's a shame that we can't "ping" users who have had their questions migrated - do they still get notifications?

Tags: discussion, migration

I was going through the Close Votes queue, and after having spent a fair while trying to get my head around this question, [Problems coding a 12 pin 7 segment display and grove temperature sensor with Arduino Uno](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/21707/problems-coding-a-12-pin-7-segment-display-and-grove-temperature-sensor-with-ard/23229#23229), and then trying to answer it to the best of my ability, given the limited information in the actual question, I have just seen that the user is not even active on SE Arduino. Hence any requests for clarification will, probably, fall on "deaf ears". Looking at the [revison/migration history](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/222112/revisions), I would not be surprised if the *relatively* new user thought that their question had be deleted/discarded/ignored/forgotten, and will not bother to revisit, or chase down, their question. I wonder if there is a question, on SE Meta, relating to new users and their possible confusion about migration?

I suppose that it is my own fault for spending so much time on it, when I should have checked the question's antecedence first.

However, it did make me wonder why we can't "ping" users in order to give them a nudge/poke, to see whether they are still interested in an answer. I guess that they may get a notification in their email, assuming that they have this setting enabled. However, in the case of migrated questions, on to sites where they are not members, do they get email notifications in such a circumstance? SE Meta is not totally clear:

- [Migrated question of non-existing user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177983/migrated-question-of-non-existing-user) - says that users are not notified
- [Are users notified when their question is migrated to a site they're not a member of?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212495/are-users-notified-when-their-question-is-migrated-to-a-site-theyre-not-a-membe) - says that they are - as this question is chronologically later, then I assume that it is safe to assume that users *do* receive notification.
- [Remind new users to create/associate accounts if a question has been migrated to a site on which the user does not have an account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148761/remind-new-users-to-create-associate-accounts-if-a-question-has-been-migrated-to) - it is not clear if this feature request was ever fulfilled, but it looks like a good idea.

It is a shame really, as a number of people seem to be willing to help this person, and many others in similar circumstances, but if they are unaware that people are adding comments and answers, would they bother hunting down their question on to a different site to which their originally asked it?

---

As a follow up, I've actually left a comment on one of the user's SO questions, where they appear to be active, mentioning that the question has a few answers...

Answer (score 1):

I think that a question still "belongs" to the user even if it is migrated, as there is an over-arching Stack Exchange account, of which the accounts on individual sites are "children". Are you sure s/he didn't get any pings from your comments?

Comment: I am not 100% sure. It _appears_ that they do, please see my updated question. Maybe my update, has turned my question into a _non-question_, or in other words, has ended up answering itself. I am still not convinced though. I guess the only way to be sure, would be to ask K-Dawg, the OP of the original question, whether they received any notifications or not.

Comment: At the risk of facing a harrasment law suit, these are [the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325751/static-sidebar-and-fluid-content-with-header-and-footer#comment60945675_35325751) that I have left for the user.

Comment: OK, very good. :)